# How to be able to use global IP in the local network?

Tags: networking, router, nat

Let's say we have:

- 192.168.0.1 router connected to internet with global IP 1.2.3.4
- 192.168.0.10 machine A with a web server serving on port 80
- 192.168.0.20 machine B (laptop)

The router is configured in NAT to route everything on port 80 to 192.168.0.10.

When I'm **outside** of this local network, http://1.2.3.4 works fine in the browser, it is well redirected to the machine A, that serves the request.

But when I'm **inside** the local network (for example with machine B, a laptop WiFi-connected to the router), doing http://1.2.3.4 in the browser does not work.

I hoped that it would work like this:

```
192.168.0.20 does a request to 1.2.3.4
the request arrives on router 192.168.0.1
router detects "1.2.3.4 is us!" so routing internally to 192.168.0.10
```

---

Application: I have a domain `example.com` and the DNS A record is set to 1.2.3.4.
Accessing `example.com` in the browser will work everything ... except if I'm in the local network of machine A. Such a shame!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research I learnt that this feature is called [Hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) or NAT loopback, and not all ISP routers support it.

In the case of my ISP router, it is unfortunately not supported.